# Make domain 301 redirect to a static WordPress page

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, 301-redirect

After adding a new page in WordPress i have this URL structure: domain.com/page. I would like to point a top level domain to this page using a PHP redirect:

```
header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' ); 
header( 'Location: http://www.new-domain.com' );
exit();
```

I know that such method is fine if i'm redirecting a new domain to an old page or perhaps to some other old domain, but the thing is that this static page was just created, so it's new and the domain was just registered, so it's also new. There are no technical issues involved, i just want to point a new domain to a new page.

Following this situation is it SEO safe to use this method? Does it have any disadvantages? What consequences may occur using this method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine.  The 301 code is exactly appropriate for the situation you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know what exactly you are trying to do with this, but the method that you are using here is safe.

Do not try to fool google with any snicky redirect, because they can track your activity from webmaster and the crawling. Be genuine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. No, it's not about fooling Google, but exactly the opposite.

Comment: ok, if you are confident about the procedure then you can implement that.